# How should I best store fixed point Decimal values in Python for cryptocurrency?

Tags: python, django, decimal

I'm playing around with developing a Django/Python app which stores, and does calculations on, cryptocurrency values. These are decimal values to 8 decimal places, eg, 0.00000008, 4.10500008, 6000.00000000.

Perhaps partly from not being confident fully in the nuances of how Python's Decimal works, and partly on advice I've seen for different languages, I was thinking it might be safer to store values as their satoshi equiv values in an BigInteger field, eg for 0.00000008 I store 8, for 4.10500008 I store 410500008 and for 6000.00000000 I store 600000000000.

Is this a good idea or should I be using Decimal with some particular setting instead?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can safely use Decimal instead. It is really decimal under the hood, i.e. there are no base-conversion errors. If you store

```
import decimal

d = decimal.Decimal('4.10500008')
```

there will be no loss of precision.

Just make sure you create the numbers by using strings, because otherwise you'll have trouble:

```
>>> decimal.Decimal(1.1)
Decimal('1.100000000000000088817841970012523233890533447265625')
```

versus:

```
>>> decimal.Decimal('1.1')
Decimal('1.1')
```

One more important thing to understand is that `decimal.Decimal` carries the precision, as well:

```
>>> decimal.Decimal('1.10')
Decimal('1.10')
```

This is very useful with financial applications.

For more information, see: https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html

**N.B.** As `Mark Dickinson` reminds below, the `decimal` module does not use arbitrary precision, the number of significant numbers in calculations is limited. This limit can be set or queried by `decimal.getcontext().prec`, and the default value is 28. The default value should be quite enough for usual financial calculations (down to billionth of cents in the US state debt), but if you need more, you may set it to a larger number.

Comment: While constructing a `Decimal` object from a decimal string doesn't involve any errors, *operations* on `Decimal` objects   are still susceptible to rounding errors.  For a quick example, try `0 + decimal.Decimal(1.1)` and see what you get.  In the OP's case, which is basically fixed-point decimal arithmetic, I'd be tempted to go for an integer-based solution instead.  (Note that Python's `Decimal` is *not* a fixed-point type; it's a floating-point type.)

Comment: @MarkDickinson: I do not agree with your example, as `decimal.Decimal('0')+decimal.Decimal('1.1')` gives `Decimal('1.1')`. The round-off error in your example occurs because an ordinary float `1.1` is not exactly `1.1`. But of course, there will be round-off errors in calculations without finite decimal representation, such as 1/3. OTOH, there should be no round-off errors with additions, multiplications or subtractions. In that sense `decimal.Decimal` is equivalent (but often easier) to fixed-point representation.

Comment: "OTOH, there should be no round-off errors with additions, multiplications or subtractions."  That's my point:  there *will* be round-off errors, if you exceed the current context precision!  And the precision is based on number of significant digits, not the number of digits after the point, so it's hard to set and use for fixed-point arithmetic (unless you just set it to some insanely high value and cross your fingers).

Comment: At the very least, advice to use `Decimal` should come with recommendations for setting the context precision, and possibly also for setting trap handlers for the `Inexact` flag.

Comment: @MarkDickinson: I see what you mean, the example did not just illustrate that problem. It seems that the default value for significant figures is 28, which is more than with `int64`, i.e. if your dynamic ranges goes beyond that (and at least beyond my bank account dynamic range), you have to be very careful with the fixed integers, as well. Anyway, you have a good point, and I'll update the answer.

Comment: Re the example: I meant that the addition in the example loses digits: after `Decimal(1.1)`, you have an exact value.  Adding `0` to that *changes* the value.  That's the precision loss I was referring to.